# How to check how arguments are passed in GDB?

Tags: c, gdb

Calling conventions are complicated, sometimes when I debug a program in GDB I would like to know how the arguments are passed.

For example, when I use the `call` instruction like this:

```
call nicefun(7)
```

I would like GDB to write me something like this:

```
I put 7 in rdi.
```

Is there such an option? Of course, checking how 7 is passed is easy, but the matter gets complicated with large structs, va_list's, etc...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there such an option?

No.

> I would like to know how the arguments are passed.

If you are debugging at assembly level, there is *no substitute* for getting familiar with the calling conventions of your platform.

If you are generally familiar with them, but forgot some detail and need a quick reminder, `x/20i target_function` usually provides sufficient hint.